# Is transposing training set affects the results with SVM

Tags: matlab, matrix, classification, svm

I am working on human age claffication where i have to classify data into two classes namely `Young` and `Old`. As a classifier i am using `SVM` and this is what i did so far to parepare the data :

1. The `TrainingSet` where it's size is (11264, 284) : where each column corresponds to an `observation` (a person). This means that i have 284 persons for the training task and 11264 features.
2. The `TestSet` is also formated as the `TrainingSet`.
3. The `Groups` (labels) is a matrix Groups(284, 1) filled with (1) for `Olds` and (-1) for `Youngs`.
4. I trained `SVM` using matlab built-in function to have the `SvmStruct'.

   ```
   SvmStruct = svmtrain(TrainingSet, Groups')
   ```
5. Then i introduce the `TestSet` using this `matlab` function in order to have the classification results.

   ```
   SvmClassify = svmclassify(SvmStruct, TestSet)
   ```

After i reviewed the `matlab` help about `SVM` i deduced that the data have to be introduced to the `SVM` classifier in a way that the each row of the `TrainingSet` corresponds to an `Observation` (a person in my case) and each column corresponds to a feature. So what i was doing so far was transposing those matrices (`TrainingSet` and `TestSet`). 
Is what i did was wrong and all the results i got are wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked at the source code for `svmtrain`, and it transposes the training data if the number of groups does not match the number of rows (`svmtrain.m`, line 249 ff, MATLAB 2015b):

```
% make sure data is the right size
if size(training,1) ~= size(groupIndex,1)
    if size(training,2) == size(groupIndex,1)
        training = training';
    else
        error(message('stats:svmtrain:DataGroupSizeMismatch'))
    end
end
```

So no, your training results are not wrong.

However, `svmclassify` does not transpose the test data, it only checks for the right number of features (`svmclassify.m`, line 63 ff.):

```
if size(sample,2)~=size(svmStruct.SupportVectors,2)
    error(message('stats:svmclassify:TestSizeMismatch'));
end
```

So this should have triggered an error (`sample` is your `TestSet`).

Comment: @zeeMonkeez thank you so much. you really saved my 6 months work !

Comment: @zeeMonkeez so i have to transpose the TestSet before performing the SvmClassify function ?

Comment: @mohammedaouledissa unless I'm missing something in `svmclassify.m`, yes. It really should trigger an error if the number of classes does not match. However, this may have changed from a previous version of MATLAB. You can always check for yourself: `edit svmclassify.m`

Comment: i've checked the svmClassify and it's as what you said, SvmClassify does not transpose the TestSet, it triggers an error if the number of classes does not match.